# MTM Test Case run does not update in all suites

Tags: tfs, automated-tests, microsoft-test-manager

I have assigned one test case to two different user stories. I know it's not the cleanest method but it helps in the case I created that.

In the test plan I added requirements and hence their respective test cases. Now this single test case is present in two different test suites since it tests two different user stories.

When I run this test case I expect it to either fail or succeed in both suites, but it seems that there are two totally different instances of that test case in the plan and I can have one passing and the other one failing.

Is there a need for such a behavior or is it unexpected, therefore a bug in MTM?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create now test plans on MTM you can specify the configurations for it and which one of them will be the default. So, when you add new requirements they automatically take the default configuration. However, you can always change it by assigning another available configuration for any requirement you want. My point is that test case, that belongs to two different User Stories, when it is assigned to the test plan has an extra information which is the configuration that it will be used to test it.

So, if your test case A is assigned to user stories A and B, and these requirements have been assigned to the same Test Plan **but** they have different configurations it is very possible the one test case instance to fail and the other to pass.